# SDL/C++ include problems

Tags: c++, types, include, sdl

I started doing game for my school project in C++ with SDL library. But I cannot find what am I doing wrong in code below.

I am using VC++ 2008,

here is the compilator output:

```
1>Compiling...
1>initGame.cpp
1>.\dec.h(4) : error C2065: 'SDL_HWSURFACE' : undeclared identifier
1>.\dec.h(4) : error C2065: 'SDL_DOUBLEBUF' : undeclared identifier
1>.\dec.h(6) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'
1>.\dec.h(6) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>.\dec.h(6) : error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>.\dec.h(6) : error C2065: 'NULL' : undeclared identifier
1>.\initgame.cpp(4) : error C2065: 'SDL_INIT_VIDEO' : undeclared identifier
1>.\initgame.cpp(4) : error C2065: 'SDL_INIT_AUDIO' : undeclared identifier
1>.\initgame.cpp(4) : error C2065: 'SDL_INIT_TIMER' : undeclared identifier
1>.\initgame.cpp(4) : error C3861: 'SDL_Init': identifier not found
1>.\initgame.cpp(5) : error C2065: 'cerr' : undeclared identifier
1>.\initgame.cpp(5) : error C2065: 'endl' : undeclared identifier
1>.\initgame.cpp(9) : error C3861: 'SDL_SetVideoMode': identifier not found
```

And here is the source

dec.h:

```
#ifndef DEC_H
#define DEC_H

int g_win_flags = SDL_HWSURFACE|SDL_DOUBLEBUF;

SDL_Surface *g_screen = NULL;

#endif
```

initGame.cpp:

```
#include "dec.h"

bool initGame(){
 if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO | SDL_INIT_AUDIO | SDL_INIT_TIMER) == -1){
  cerr << "Unable to initialize SDL" << endl;
  return false;
 }

 g_screen = SDL_SetVideoMode(640, 480, 0, g_win_flags);

 return true;
}
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SDL.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "SDL.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "SDLmain.lib")

using namespace std;

#include "initGame.cpp"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

 initGame();
 return 0;
}
```

I would be very grateful if somebody could help me.

Thanks in advance a have a nice day :)

Comment: @Zod -- Undid your retagging.  This is a c++ issue.  The problem is not specific to visual c++.

Comment: Oh man, there are just so many little things in this code that raise warnings to me.  Some might call it code style though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Move `#include <SDL.h>` to dec.h.  When compiling initGame.cpp, you never told the compiler to look at SDL.h, so it couldn't figure out what any of those `SDL_` things were and got very confused.

Also, don't `#include` one *.cpp file from another.  Take the `#include "initGame.cpp"` out of main.cpp.

Comment: Thanks for answer. But I'm little confused, why should I take #include "initGame.cpp" out of main.cpp? How would I access initGame then?

Comment: You should put a _declaration_ of `initGame` in a header file (like dec.h or a new file initGame.h): `bool initGame();`

Answer (score 2):

1. In init.h include the SDL headers,
   and cstring for NULL
2. in init.cpp include iostream

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the include.

Each cpp file (known as a compilation unit) is self-contained, so you need to give each one all the definitions and suchlike that it needs. ie, initGame.cpp has an include for dec.h, but that doesn't have one for sdl.h.

So: either add the 'include  to initgame.cpp or to dec.h.